# SQLAlchemy: Multiple foreign keys to same table with compound primary key

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

In SQLAlchemy, imagine we have a table `Foo` with a compound primary key, and `Bar`, which has two foreign key constrains linking it to `Foo` (each `Bar` has two `Foo` objects).

My problem is with the `relationship` function, which makes me repeat the information (in the `primaryjoin`) which I have already given in the `ForeightKeyConstraint` (violating DRY). Is there some other way of structuring this so that I don't have to repeat information? Some way of passing the relevant `ForeignKeyConstraint` to `relationship`?

```
class Foo(Base):
    __tablename__ = "Foo"
    id_1 = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    id_2 = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

class Bar(Base):
    __tablename__ = "Bar"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

    foo_1_id_1 = Column(Integer)
    foo_1_id_2 = Column(Integer)

    foo_2_id_1 = Column(Integer)
    foo_2_id_2 = Column(Integer)

    __table_args__ = (
            ForeignKeyConstraint(
                [foo_1_id_1,foo_1_id_2],
                [Foo.id_1,Foo.id_2]
                ),
            ForeignKeyConstraint(
                [foo_2_id_1,foo_2_id_2],
                [Foo.id_1,Foo.id_2]
                )
            )

    foo_1 = relationship(Foo,primaryjoin="(Bar.foo_1_id_1 == Foo.id_1) & (Bar.foo_1_id_2 == Foo.id_2)")
    foo_2 = relationship(Foo,primaryjoin="(Bar.foo_2_id_1 == Foo.id_1) & (Bar.foo_2_id_2 == Foo.id_2)")
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [relationship()](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/orm/relationships.html#sqlalchemy.orm.relationship), as it is, cannot determine its full configuration. This is always the case when there is more than one way to refer to the related table.
In your example it seems like sqlalchemy could be smart enough to guess by the names of the columns, but this is not what does and it should not.

Although it might seem as if you have information **repetition**, in fact you are just **being specific** about your relationship configuration.

There is, in fact, option to specify `foreign_keys` in the [relationship()](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/orm/relationships.html#sqlalchemy.orm.relationship) configuration, but currently is serves somewhat different purpose, so you still will need to configure `primaryjoin`.

Comment: Thanks. But there IS repetition. I realize it doesn't know which `ForeignKeyConstraint` to use. But if, for example I could somehow give a reference to the relevant `ForeignKeyConstraint` to the `relationship`, and it could figure out the join expression for itself (like it does when there is only one `ForeignKeyConstraint` to the given table) then that would eliminate the repetition of the details of the join.

Comment: True, and in fact, as mentioned, there is a possibility to provide `foreign_keys` to the relationship, but currently it is not used to infer the `primaryjoin` condition. Your case is good example where it could be used this way. But as mentioned in the answer, *currently* it does not. But why don't you create a feature request ticket on http://www.sqlalchemy.org/trac/

Comment: I shall then, Wanted to make sure I wasn't missing something obvious, which has mostly been the case so far with my SQLAlchemy woes!

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `foreign_keys` and a list of Foreign Keys.

See [Multiple Join Paths](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/join_conditions.html#handling-multiple-join-paths)

```
foo_1 = relationship(Foo, foreign_keys=[foo_1_id_1, foo_2_id_2])
foo_2 = relationship(Foo, foreign_keys=[foo_2_id_1, foo_2_id_2])
```

Comment: The link is invalid.